# Diferença entre If e Elif

Tags: python

Qual a diferença entre os dois trechos de código

```
if variavel < 10:
   variavel = 1
if variavel >= 10 and <15:
   variavel = 2
.
.
.
else 
   variavel = 0
```

---

```
if variavel < 10:
   variavel = 1
elif variavel >= 10 and <15:
   variavel = 2
.
.
.
else 
   variavel = 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neste trecho se variavel for menor que 10, primeiro vai setar o valor 1 e depois o `else` da segunda if vai setar `0`, isto porque são duas ifs separadas:

```
if variavel < 10:
   variavel = 1
if variavel >= 10 and <15:
   variavel = 2
.
.
.
else:
   variavel = 0
```

Aqui o `elif` faz parte da "logica" do `if`, ou seja se variável for menor que 10 ele só vai setar o `variavel = 1`:

```
if variavel < 10:
   variavel = 1
elif variavel >= 10 and <15:
   variavel = 2
.
.
.
else: 
   variavel = 0
```

Resumindo, o `elif` é uma condição de `if` junto com `else`, seria praticamente o mesmo que fazer isto:

```
if variavel < 10:
   variavel = 1
else:
    if variavel >= 10 and <15:
       variavel = 2
    .
    .
    .
    else: 
       variavel = 0
```

Diferente de outras linguagens o Python não usa `{...}`, isto porque ele trabalha com [indentation <sup>PEP 8</sup>](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (apesar da tradução da palavra ser algo como "recuamento", costumamos adapta-la do inglês para "indentação", não que seja a maneira correta, mas talvez irá ouvir falar muito assim)

> **Nota IMPORTANTE:** acredito que esta if esteja errada `elif variavel >= 10 and <15:`, o correto seria `elif variavel >= 10 and variavel < 15:`

Ou seja para definir uma `if` será necessário os espaços (note que o python3 não aceita mais misturar tabs) nas linhas seguintes:

```
if ... :
    exec1
    exec2
    exec3
```

Se fizer isto o `exec3` estará fora da condição:

```
if ... :
    exec1
    exec2
exec3
```

Comment: Sobre o uso do portuguÊs "indentação" - é efetivamente como a comunidade Python brasileira usa. Por vários anos, o Luciano Ramalho (fundador da assoc. Python Brasil e autor de Fluent Python) e eu tentamos usar outros termos  - ele tendo sugerido que o correto poderia ser "endentação" (e mais tarde descobrindo que não). O uso de "recuo" simplemente não remete a código o suficiente, apesar de ser um Português já existente. Então, melhor mesmo seguir usando "identação" e deixar que as gramáticas se atualizem com o uso real da língua, no dia a dia, em alguns ano, como acontece com todos os termos.

Answer (score 2):

O If serve para verificar uma condição e o elif serve para verificar outra condição caso a condição do If seja falsa. No código não há muita diferença,  o elif vai garantir que aquela condição seja verificada caso o If seja falso, diferente dos dois If que são 'fluxos' independentes.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, um `if` é o primeiro if, o `else` é quando você quer fazer ele completar alguma ação se o `if` for falso, e `elif` é quando você tem um `if` dentro de um `else`

Exemplo:
este trecho de código:

```
if(x==1):
    # para if verdadeiro

else:

    if(x==21):
        # para o if dentro do else verdadeiro
```

é igual a esse:

```
if(x==1):
    # primeiro if verdadeiro
elif(x==21):
    #segundo if verdadeiro
```

que também é igual a esse(embora seja uma forma "errada" de escrever, por "quebrar" um if/else associado em diversos outros if's):

```
if(x==1):
    # primeiro if verdadeiro
if(x==21):
    #segundo if verdadeiro
```

Answer (score -2):

E sem falar que você pode usar mais de um elif ( não que seja sempre útil, mas fica aqui a ilustração.

```
 n = 3
if n == 1:
    print('n == 1')
elif n == 2:
    print('n == 2')
elif n == 3:
    print('n == 3')
elif n == 4:
    print('n == 4')
```